# Display list of strings with only one string which is separated by (,) and (\n)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I need to convert list of strings which contains one long string where values are separated with `,` and `\n`. Example:

```
string[] namesArray = {"Name1,Surname1", "Name2,Surname2", "Name3,Surname3"};`

string nameSting = "";

foreach(string nameFromArray in namesArray) {
  nameSting += nameFromArray + "\n";
}

List<string> namesList = new List<string>();
namesList.Add(nameSting);
```

My question is how can I process `namesList` so `Console.WriteLine` outputs the following format:

```
1. Name1 Surname1
2. Name2 Surname2
3. Name3 Surname3
```

Please note that nothing above can be changed. I know it's a weird code but it's a very simplified way to show how API returns data which needs to be converted in the format described above.

Comment: Can you just split your string by `\n` and then by `,` and then collect your (name, surname) pairs as you want? Or there are some additional limitations which preventing from doing this?

Comment: The code posted in the question seems to be doing what you describe you want, but it's very inefficient. You should consider to change it either to use a string builder or simply string.Join (which I suspect would do even better than a string builder under some circumstances).

Comment: Unfortunattelly code can't be changed. I tried to output it with loop like this: ` foreach(var x in namesList){
     Console.WriteLine(x.Replace(",", " "));
 }` however I also need to add index before each name so if the string gets longer in the future the loop will still keep track of order.

Comment: you are creating a list to store only on item, why the list??

Comment: Actually I don't see the Problem, are you need incremental index? Where is the console print in your code ? What is the exact requirement, please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show what you have and what you expect.

Comment: Yes, incremental index needs to be placed before each name like in the second snippet. All the requirements are in the first snippet, basically `namesList ` is what needs to be printed just like 2nd snippets shows.

Answer (score 1):

The following

```
string[] namesArray = {"Name1,Surname1", "Name2,Surname2", "Name3,Surname3"};
int index = 1; 
namesArray.ToList().ForEach(n => {Console.WriteLine(index + ". " + n.Replace(',', ' ')); index++;});
```

will output:

```
1. Name1 Surname1
2. Name2 Surname2
3. Name3 Surname3
```

Don't forget to include the following using statements:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Answer (score 0):

Split by new line and then split by comma

```
var names = namesList
    .SelectMany(t => t.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None))
    .Select(name => name.Split(','))
    .Select((name, index) => (Index: index, FirstName: name[0], Surname: name[1]));

foreach(var name in names)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{name.Index}. {name.FirstName} {name.Surname}");
}
```